# Can't search for flags in qalter's man page?

Tags: search, man, options

I was trying to find out what `qalter`'s `-r` flag does, but I can't search for `-r` when viewing the man page for it (pattern not found). Yet it's clearly there. If you scroll down a bit you'll see it. Why can't I search for flags in this man page? This [online](http://cf.ccmr.cornell.edu/cgi-bin/w3mman2html.cgi?qalter%281B%29) version seems to work fine though.

Comment: Works for me, pressing `/-r` plus `Enter`.

Comment: That's what I tried. I'm on gentoo using `xfce4-terminal-0.6.3` if that matters. qalter's man page is in the package `man-pages-posix-2013a`.

Comment: What about man pages of other commands (e.g. ls)?

Comment: I tried and it works in ls, gcc and cat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sometimes happens that man pages contain formatting commands and settings that lead to certain characters being rendered using various non-ASCII characters. This can be `⎪` instead of `|`, `­` (soft hyphen) or `‐` (hyphen) or `‑` (non-breaking hyphen) instead of `-` (ASCII hyphen-minus), `∗` instead of `*`, etc.

Try searching for non-ASCII characters in the man page:

```
LC_COLLATE=C LESS='+/[^ -~]' man qalter
```

You can force the man page to be rendered in ASCII by choosing an ASCII character set:

```
LC_CTYPE=C man qalter
```

Having shell options rendered with a non-ASCII alternative to `-` is a bug, probably in the man page soucre. I don't know enough *roff to know what the bug might be.